# How can I calculate the Jacobian for a set of functions?

Tags: functions

I want to calculate the Jacobian of three functions. Following the mathematical way of calculating I do:

```
u[x_, y_, z_] := 9 x^2 y^2 + z E^x
v[x_, y_, z_] := x y + x^2 y^3 + 2*z
w[x_, y_, z_] := Cos[x]*Sin[z]*E^y
{
 {D[u[x, y, z], x], D[u[x, y, z], y], D[u[x, y, z], z]},
 {D[v[x, y, z], x], D[v[x, y, z], y], D[v[x, y, z], z]},
 {D[w[x, y, z], x], D[w[x, y, z], y], D[w[x, y, z], z]}
}
```

Where `E` is the Euler number expressed in Mathematica.

And I get the Jacobian.

I have seen that there is a function named `JacobianMatrix` which I understand shall give the same result.

I try this without success:

```
JacobianMatrix[{u[x, y, z], v[x, y, z], w[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}]
```

- Would that function be used to calculate the Jacobian?
- If so, what is wrong in the way I am invoking it?

Comment: `D[{u[x, y, z], v[x, y, z], w[x, y, z]}, {{x, y, z}, 1}]` or `Grad[{u[x, y, z], v[x, y, z], w[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}] `

Comment: and `Det@Grad` is the Jacobian.

Comment: If you mean [this](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/JacobianMatrix) then the syntax is `ResourceFunction["JacobianMatrix"][{u[x,y,z],v[x,y,z],w[x,y,z]},{x,y,z}]`. Anyhow, I am with @cvgmt. I think it would be good if typing "Jacobian" into the documentation center search bar would direct one to `D` and `Grad`, as first and second search result, not to some ResourceFunction.

Comment: @user293787 I guess since `Jacobian` is a system symbol and option to `FindRoot`, I'd expect `FindRoot` to be the top hit. For me, it's 4th and `D` is 5th. I don't get a resource function hit on the first page. Maybe it's a difference in how our systems are set up or versions or the online docs (I'm on V13.1/Mac). (My top 2 hits are optimization tutorials and the 3rd is `CoordinateTransformData`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I was here https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=Jacobian where 1st and 2nd place are resource functions. Locally I do not get resource functions, but the rest is in the same order with `D` in 5th place (Version 12.3/Linux).

Answer (score 2):

I think the shortest way to achieve what you are looking for is as follows:

---

u[x_, y_, z_] := 9 x^2 y^2 + z E^x;

v[x_, y_, z_] := x y + x^2 y^3 + 2 z;

w[x_, y_, z_] := Cos[x] Sin[z] E^y;

jacobian = D[{u[x, y, z], v[x, y, z], w[x, y, z]}, {{x, y, z}}]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Try this]

```
f[x1, x2, x3] = {9 x1^2 x2^2 + x3 E^x1, x1 x2 + x1^2 x2^3 + 2*x3, Cos[x1]*Sin[x3]*E^x2}

(J = Table[ Table[D[f[x1, x2, x3][[i]], xi], {xi, {x1, x2, x3}}], {i, 1, 3}]) // MatrixForm
```

I hope this will help you.
All the best

Comment: Please post the code instead of pictures.

Comment: f[x1, x2, x3] = {9 x1^2 x2^2 + x3 E^x1, x1 x2 + x1^2 x2^3 + 2*x3, 
  Cos[x1]*Sin[x3]*E^x2}
(J = Table[
    Table[D[f[x1, x2, x3][[i]], xi], {xi, {x1, x2, x3}}], {i, 1, 
     3}]) // MatrixForm

Comment: Although this generates the desired Jacobian matrix, it does not answer the OP's question.